# Error -Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Criteria

Tags: 2011, api, broker

I have below two Criteria -

1. `Criteria searchCriteria = CriteriaFactory.And(ItemSchemaCriteria, PublicationCriteria);`
2. `finalCriteria = CriteriaFactory.And(andCriteria);`

here `andCriteria` is an array of some Keyword Criteria.

Now when I try to add these both criteria and assign it in another Criteria named `myCriteria` the as below:

```
myCriteria = searchCriteria.addCriteria(finalCriteria);
```

Below compilation error comes:

> "Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Criteria"

**NOTE:** As I debug and found that both searchCriteria and finalCriteria are not NULL.

Could somebody give me some pointers here to fix this error?

Comment: I suspect that addCriteria is a void method and it modifies your search criteria in place, hence you see that error when you try to assign the result of addCritera to your myCriteria variable. Can you post a more complete example of your code?

Comment: Not sure if this is the right place for this question given that this is pretty much a pure programming problem and not necessarily related to Tridion (aside from the fact that Tridion libraries are being used).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As hinted at by Nick, the `Criteria.AddCriteria` method doesn't return a `Criteria` object, so you can't assign it as you're trying to. What you probably want is something like this:

```
searchCriteria.AddCriteria(finalCriteria);
myCriteria = searchCriteria;
```

Note that if you do this, `searchCriteria` and `myCriteria` will be the same object instance, so changes to one will affect the other (until one of them is reassigned).

Comment: yes, Ant you are correct. Thanks to NVanderEnde also.